# GSS_S_FAILURE on gss_import_name API

Tags: api, gssapi

So here's my code:

```
    #include "QCSRC/GSSAPI"                                   
    void main() {                                             
      OM_uint32 wRC;                                          
      OM_uint32 minor_status;                                 
      OM_uint32 time_received;                                
      gss_buffer_desc test;                                   
      gss_name_t target_name;                                 
      char *service_name;  

      service_name = "nfs";                                   
      test.length = 3;                                        
      test.value = service_name;                              
      wRC = gss_import_name(&minor_status, &test,             
            GSS_C_NO_OID , &target_name);                      
      if (wRC == GSS_S_FAILURE) {                             
        printf("GSS_S_FAILURE\n");                            
      }                                                       
    }
```

It would already be helpful to know if I use the C structs correctly.

I get `GSS_S_FAILURE` on that simple call. Documentation said this is a General error and the minor Status should contain more Information. But the minor Status is returned as `2529639135` that cannot be found in this [list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1331/kerberrs-1/index.html).

This should be a simple Task, but either my C programming skills are not good enough yet, or I lack some Basic understanding of GSS APIs or the implementation on the AS/400.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself - "step 2" on this page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzakh/rzakhconfigd2.htm#configure2